# JetBrains Rider Metadata for Net Core classes

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, rider

In VSCode when I need to check the documentation for a System Class, say for instance the Console class, I can just go to to reference of the class and see the metadata, like this:

[image]

While Rider would just go the class implementation instead. Is this a feature that Rider does not have? I can't quite to find any info on their documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me "View | Quick Documentation" on a symbol is usually sufficient. It has a shortcut depending on the shortcut schema.

Metadata view is available also: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Metadata_Sources.html